# Switching Nameservers on main server domain

Tags: dns, webserver, cpanel, whm, nameservers

Got a bit of a tricky one here.  I'm gonna use example to domain names to make this simple.

So I have a server: `whm.example.com`.  The main domain `example.com` was bought using Fasthosts, not bought with the web hosting company.

Configured in the WHM/cPanel, look to be custom nameservers, `ns1.example.com` and `ns2.example.com`. The domain name in Fasthosts of course points to `ns1.example.com` and `ns2.example.com`.

On my web server (`whm.example.com`) they are multiple websites.  I want to migrate `example.com` to a new web server, which would mean updating the nameservers for that domain.

Because the domain, web server and the nameservers take the same name, would pointing `example.com` to new nameservers (`ns1.website1.com` & `ns2.website1.com`) cause all websites that run on the `whm.example.com` server to go down?

Let's say I have a website called `mywebsite.example` on the `whm.example.com` server.  I assume changing the nameserves on this particular domain wouldn't be an issue, as it isn't directly linked to the server name.

If someone could give me a real idiots guide on the solution to this, that would be fantastic.  I'm not web server tech savvy, it is far from my domain.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to change the host for your main domain `example.com` while remaining rest of the subdomains, you'd just need to update your `A` record to your new web host.
Moving nameservers usually wouldn't have downtime if both of them have the same records already configured.